# Better way to retrieve all rows from a table using PDO fetchAll() or fetch() inside a function

Tags: php, pdo

actually in my php webapp i've always used functions to retrieve ALL rows IN A VARIABLE from a database table and print it in a loop using an HTML table, like this, to separate logic from views:

My functions.php: (contains all functions to connect and retrieve datas)

```
<?php

   function get_table_rows($table, $filters = []) {
       //connection using PDO (omitted)

       $sql = "SELECT $table.* FROM $table WHERE 1"; //semplified without filters
       $rs = $db->prepare($sql);
       $rs->execute();  
       return $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   }
```

I prefer separate functions/logic from HTML (like MVC):

My index.php: (for a general page on my webapp)

```
<?php

  include "functions.php";

  ...omitted

  $results = get_table_rows($table);

  include "html.php";
```

My html.php: (for the view)

```
 <html>
 ...
 <body>
    <div>
       <table>
          <thead>
             <tr><th>COLUMN 1</th><th>COLUMN 2</th></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php
                  foreach ( $results as $row ) {
                        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['Field1'] . '</td></td>' . $row['Field2'] . '</td></tr>';
                  }
            ?>
          </tbody>
       </table>

       ....
     </html>
```

Now the problem is that i've a database table with a lot of rows, and if I use my actual method (fetchAll() function) i get FATAL ERROR MEMORY EXAUST.

Better solution is to white something like this, to prevent creation of a BIG variable:

```
    $sql = "SELECT $table.* FROM $table WHERE 1"; //semplified without filters
    $rs = $db->prepare($sql);
    $rs->execute();  
    while ($row = $rs->fetch()) {
         //do something like:
         echo '<tr><td>' . $row['Field1'] . '</td></td>' . $row['Field2'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
```

But in this case I need to write this code in my view (html.php) so I need to mix controllers with pure views:

```
         <html>
 ...
 <body>
    <div>
       <table>
          <thead>
             <tr><th>COLUMN 1</th><th>COLUMN 2</th></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php
                   $sql = "SELECT $table.* FROM $table WHERE 1";
                   $rs = $db->prepare($sql);
                   $rs->execute();  
                    while ($row = $rs->fetch()) {
                        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['Field1'] . '</td></td>' . $row['Field2'] . '</td></tr>';
                  }
            ?>
          </tbody>
       </table>

       ....
     </html>
```

My question is: what is best way to use a "while ($row = $rs->fetch())" inside a view, to prevent MEMORY EXAUST ERROR, without write inside a view the rest of code (SELECT QUERY etc..) ?

I specific I need, in this case, retrieve ALL data, **so I can't and i don't want to use methods like paginations**...

Please ignore "injection problem"... i've reported only a semplified example without binding.

Any suggest? thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense either. Instead of crashing PHP you will crash your browser. What gives? You should limit the amount of data displayed, using pagination

Comment: Besides, you have bigger problems to attend. get_table_rows is wide open to SQL injections. And also, get_table_rows shouldn't create a connection of its own, but accept it as a parameter

Comment: @YourCommonSense of course I've semplified the example... in the real code I use binding and pass variables to it. I can't use pagination. I need all data because I need ALL (in a specific table... not in all tables)

Comment: Well, how many rows in this table?

Comment: @YourCommonSense about 408.000

Comment: And your browser indeed can show them all? Last time I checked, mine choked at several thousand

Comment: I seems to use "get_table_rows()" to return also already the "html" code, in this case all the TRs row... if I want to use "while with fetch()"

Comment: ...and it will contain a variable with 408.000 rows of HTML which is likely below your memory limit as well

Comment: Even if you can technically manage to display this quantity of data in one screen without a performance issue, it's completely overwhelming and meaningless for humans. No-one can possibly manage to understand that quantity of data in one display. It's massive a UX fail. So for that reason alone you should paginate it, regardless of any technical concerns.

Comment: I you don't want to deal with PDO statements in your view (fair enough) you can wrap your result set in a iterable that fetches a row at a time. Your view will just see an array-like object it can foreach. But, as said, you'll be just moving the crash somewhere else. If you use a templating engine, the template will eventually exhaust memory. If you manage to send it to the browser, the browser will struggle to render it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález well, PDO statement is *already* iterable, so technically it doesn't need any additional wrapping (though architecturally indeed it's better to wrap it into a portable generator). But I believe that this is not a real question and want to hear the actual problem before offering a solution. Besides, in case of database interaction, making a query unbuffered is no less important